# NuxtJS (Vue.js) Google Maps & Autocomplete inside v-if won't show once toggled, only on initial page load

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, vue-component

Setting up the base functionality of a really simple internal site, I have a checkbox to toggle a div on/off (default is on), inside that div is Google Maps & Autocomplete.

On initial page load Google Maps & Autocomplete appear and work successfully, however if toggled off and back on, the page is either blank or displays an error `Map: Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed undefined.` Screen recording of the behavior: https://i.imgur.com/DhShl1s.mp4

**main.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    Hi {{ username }}
    <input
      v-model="businessName"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Business Name"
    /><br /><br />

    In-store Address:<br />
    <input type="checkbox" @click="toggle()" />Not applicable<br /><br />
    <div v-if="instore">
      <input type="text" ref="citySearch" @changed="changed" /><br /><br />
      <div style="height:800px;width:800px" ref="map"></div>
      <br /><br />
    </div>
    <button type="button" @click="updateMap">Submit</button><br />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      businessName: "",
      businessAddress: "",
      instore: true
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$maps.makeAutoComplete(this.$refs.citySearch);
    this.$maps.showMap(this.$refs.map, -33.86, 151.2);
  },
  computed: {
    username() {
      return this.$store.state.username;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggle() {
      this.instore = !this.instore;
      this.$maps.makeAutoComplete(this.$refs.citySearch);
      this.$maps.showMap(this.$refs.map, -33.86, 151.2);
    },
    submit(e) {
      if (!this.businessName || !this.businessAddress) {
        return;
      }
      this.$store.commit("add_business", this.name, this.address);
    },
    updateMap() {
      this.$maps.showMap(this.$refs.map, this.lat, this.lng);
    },
    changed(event) {
      console.log(event);
      const place = event.detail;
      this.$maps.showMap(
        this.$refs.map,
        place.geometry.location.lat(),
        place.geometry.location.lng()
      );
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**maps.client.js:**

```
  let isLoaded = false;
  let waiting = [];

  addScript();
  inject("maps", {
    showMap,
    makeAutoComplete
  });

  function addScript() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initGoogleMap";
    script.async = true;
    window.initGoogleMap = initGoogleMap;
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  }

  function initGoogleMap() {
    isLoaded = true;
    waiting.forEach(item => {
      if (typeof item.fn === "function") {
        item.fn(...item.arguments);
      }
    });
    waiting = [];
  }

  function makeAutoComplete(input) {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      waiting.push({ fn: makeAutoComplete, arguments });
      return;
    }
    const autoComplete = new window.google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autoComplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      const place = autoComplete.getPlace();

      input.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("changed", { detail: place }));
    });
  }

  function showMap(canvas, lat, lng) {
    if (!isLoaded) {
      waiting.push({
        fn: showMap,
        arguments
      });
      return;
    }
    const mapOptions = {
      zoom: 18,
      center: new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      disableDefaultUI: true,
      zoomControl: true
    };
    const map = new window.google.maps.Map(canvas, mapOptions);
    const position = new window.google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    const marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({ position });
    marker.setMap(map);

    return;
  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, I am very new to Vue.JS, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `v-if` to a `v-show` solved the issue, not sure if it is the best method but it works for now.